# Convert a datetime array in timestamp array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, datetime, timestamp, python-datetime

I have to convert a datetime array into a timestamp array in python. My code `t = np.asarray([(dt.datetime(yy,mm,dd,hh).timestamp()) for yy,mm,dd,hh in zip(year,months,days,hours)])` doesn't work and I have not any ideas to make it functionate. Have someone any ideas to fix this problem?

Thank you so much.

Comment: please provide more info. I think year,months,days and hours must have the same size.

Comment: Yes, of course. Year, months, days and hours have the same size and they have been extracted by an xls file. I need timestamp to convert xls in mat file

Comment: please provide a [mre]. with the information given at the moment, your problem cannot be reproduced.